# Are OAuth2 Scopes for application permissions?

Tags: oauth-2.0

Is it valid to use OAuth2 scope for your own users to determine if they have permissions to do actions in your own API? It sounds like scope is more for communicating permissions between auth providers.

Answer (score 0):

From the OAuth2.0 specification ([RFC6749 - Accessing Protected Resources](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-7)

> The resource server MUST validate the access token and ensure that it has not expired and that its scope covers the requested resource.

It is clear that scopes are part of the authorization process at the resource server, but they reflect the answer to the question "what is the client (aka "App") allowed to do on my behalf?" and not "what is the user allowed to do?". The latter is defined in more or less complex policies whereas the first is defined during registration of the client and an Access Token may or may not contain all scopes requested. Scopes are the contract between the client, API and Authorization Server.

Having said that, using information like roles in scopes may end up in a high number of scopes which are hard to maintain. An API should handle generic scopes and fetch more details for determining the user's permissions from an external system (like getting the user's role). Consider using OpenID and claims instead. Claims are properties about the user which means your API can act on those properties instead of making extra calls.